# Android VideoView Activity crashing

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, android-videoview

I used the tutorial here (https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-videoview-example/) to build a videoview activity in my app though it keeps crashing when it's opened. I can't figure it out to save my life. I've checked the other posts on here and none of the suggestions have

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView myVideoView;
    private int position = 0;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private MediaController mediaControls;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // set the main layout of the activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set the media controller buttons
        if (mediaControls == null) {
            mediaControls = new MediaController(DemoActivity.this);
        }

        //initialize the VideoView
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        // create a progress bar while the video file is loading
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DemoActivity.this);
        // set a title for the progress bar
        progressDialog.setTitle("JavaCodeGeeks Android Video View Example");
        // set a message for the progress bar
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //set the progress bar not cancelable on users' touch
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // show the progress bar
        progressDialog.show();

        try {
            //set the media controller in the VideoView
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);

            //set the uri of the video to be played
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demo));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        //we also set an setOnPreparedListener in order to know when the video file is ready for playback
        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // close the progress bar and play the video
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //if we have a position on savedInstanceState, the video playback should start from here
                myVideoView.seekTo(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    myVideoView.start();
                } else {
                    //if we come from a resumed activity, video playback will be paused
                    myVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //we use onSaveInstanceState in order to store the video playback position for orientation change
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", myVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
        myVideoView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //we use onRestoreInstanceState in order to play the video playback from the stored position
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
        myVideoView.seekTo(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error what you are getting

Comment: Not sure is this helps but it's the only thing I could see that points out something specific...Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.VideoView.requestFocus()' on a null object reference

Comment: This actually means that in your main_activity lauout the VideoView (R.id.video_view) does not exists. As in the answer below by @phongvan Please have one layout for the activity which has the VideoView in it.
paste the content for both the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code have two `setContentView()` for two layout. That is reason of your error. You need `merge` two layout and sure that `VideoView` available on that view.

Comment: That did it. It was an oversight in a couple areas. I removed the second setContentView and changed the first to content_demo that it should have been. activity_quote doesn't contain my videoview. DOH! Thanks for pointing that out. Much appreciated.